# Prompt asking for user input before starting selenium and storing the input for later use, in python

Tags: python, html, selenium, user-input

I have this very untidy and a beginner like script to automate some web browsing.

But before this whole thing runs I would like to begin with a prompt that asks the user to enter some input and store that input to different variables that I could call later for selenium to use later at a certain stage of the browsing - when I need to input a message.

How should I approch this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains




driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("website")

driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("email address")
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("pass123")
driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()

driver.get("website")
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.find_element_by_id("ui-id-6").click()


day = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(day).click().perform()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li[1]/h3/a[3]').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)


driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div[2]/form/div[3]/ul[1]/li[4]/i').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div[2]/form/div[3]/ul[1]/li[3]/i').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div[2]/form/div[3]/ul[1]/li[2]/i').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div[2]/form/div[3]/ul[1]/li[1]/i').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this like any other python input variable, it is no different just because you are using selenium.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
```

```py
print("Enter data here")
variable = input()
```

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("website")

driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("email address")
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("pass123")
driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()

driver.get("website")
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.find_element_by_id("ui-id-6").click()


day = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(day).click().perform()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li[1]/h3/a[3]').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)


driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div[2]/form/div[3]/ul[1]/li[4]/i').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div[2]/form/div[3]/ul[1]/li[3]/i').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div[2]/form/div[3]/ul[1]/li[2]/i').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div[2]/form/div[3]/ul[1]/li[1]/i').click()
```